# How to delete duplicates from each row but not delete the whole column

Tags: vba, excel

For context, I have a worksheet with job titles in Column A, then in columns B onwards, it has the name of a person who does that job. However, as it is populated from multiple projects, some job titles have duplicates in the row, where the same person does the same job on different projects. What I need to do is delete the duplicates from each row. All solutions I have tried have given me errors.

Can anyone help?

The data gets to its current form using VBA, copying it from another sheet, so if it could be integrated into the copying, it wouldn't be a problem.

update:
So in an earlier part of the macro, I have to do this, but for a single column. This works:

```
 For np = lastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D1:D" & np), Range("D" & np).Text) > 1 Then
    Range("D" & np).ClearContents
    End If
    Next np
```

However, when I tried to add another loop outside this one, and change the D1:D to a variable, I fall down.

And what I want it to do is go from the top 4 rows in the picture, to the bottom 4. I have 78 jobs, and some of them have 20 people including the duplicates http://picture.ms/images/2013/09/18/Capture1.png:

[image: SO18879773 question example]

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results**.

Comment: So you only want to delete duplicate cells, and leave that cell blank? Or shift the remaining data up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use two loops, how about something like this

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

     For j = i + 1 To Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 1) Then
            If i <> j Then
                'just clear the duplicate cell...
                Cells(j, 1).ClearContents

                'or to delete the entire row if a duplicate is found...
                'Cells(j, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End If
   Next

 Next

End Sub
```

NB - I've used Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row to get the last row of data in column A, in Excel2007 and above there more rows on a worksheet, but it sounds like your data is much less than this anyway